# Mercurial's authors description

Tags: mercurial

I'm trying to change Mercurial's template.

When I push some files to my repository, the log files list my PC's name, not user's name that is logged in.
I don't want the PC's name, I want logged user's name shows up.
How I do it?

Comment: You *don't push* (I think), but *commit*

Comment: Yes I push the files.
I have the file in my computer, so I have to commit them into a specific remote server like 192.168.135.52:9855/mymercurial/mySystem

I can do that, but in show log the name who posted the files are my PC's name, not the logged user

Comment: You **push previously committed** file, **committed** under bad name - push doesn't change recorded author-name. You *have to learn* Mercurial workflow and correct terms. Praveen-K answer is totally correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Praveen-K has the right answer and Lazy Badger and Lasse have the details you're missing.  Here it is spelled out, but go pick Praveen's answer:

The user name you're seeing in/on your remote repository **are completely unrelated to**:

- Any settings on your repository/server
- The username you use to authenticate to your repository

Instead that string, called 'author' is burned into the changeset (commit) at commit time and is entirely crafted on your "PC".  You could set it to anything you want and once you push that commit to the repository that's how it will display.

At your current skill level you're not going to successfully change that string in commits you've already made, but if you dive into a good explanation (not lookup commands) like the hg book you'll come away understanding things.

Comment: Thank Ry4an. I know people generally do not read carefully, even i faced the same problem, i had to send to build to my clients and written step by step but they did not follow, and at last i had to end up by making video :P

Answer (score 1):

Make the entry in to your [hgrc](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hgrc.5.html) file. This file should be in your .hg/ directory (it may be in your repo or you can do in your home directory) and if it is not exist make the file with the name of hgrc in that folder.

> [ui]
>
> ```
> username = Your Name <your@mail>
> ```

Comment: What you tried and how you tried ? As @Lazy Badger suggested, the username will appear in your hg log after commit.

Comment: Ok sorry but need to ask you, can you tell us the steps what you did? where you make the hgrc file and what you did after that?

Comment: [I'm sorry, but I don't know how I break line in comments :]
my hgrc file name is hgweb.cfg
it's in c:\webconfig\mercurial\hgweb.cfg (it's a custom folder)

its contents:

[paths]
Direct = C:\MercurialRepository\Direct

[web]
style = monoblue
allow_push = *
push_ssl = false

[ui]
ramon = Ramon <ramon@domain.com.br>
crispim = Cleiton <cleiton@domain.com.br>

Comment: Okay then you did not mention that you set up the hg using apache. can you show me you hgweb.cfg entry ? Just look at http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/HgWebDirStepByStep#Provide_more_information_about_it

Comment: @Praveen-K - hgweb is irrelevant for **local commit**. Global or repo-specific rc-file - obviously relevant

Comment: hgweb.cfg entry ? What you mean?

But look at this:
http://192.168.131.58:9088/onixsat/Direct is my files development repository. 
When I click in "log" link I have some like==> age:15 seconds ago, author:TIINTERNO, description: Merging the files.

Look this image [link](https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-q1r7Lu84gDc/T3oDHQ-VOmI/AAAAAAAAAU0/IsLLpNhpNno/s755/crm+branche.JPG)

Comment: It has to say **username =**, not **ramon =**, and it'll only take effect on new commits.